# Azure DevOps show/hide fields depending on conditions

Tags: azure-devops

Is is possible to make a custom rule in Azure DevOps that either shows or hides a field in a work item depending on a condition?

For example:

**Condition 1**: When a work item is created

**Action 1**: Hide field X

**Condition 2**: When work item state changes from Active to Resolved

**Action 2**: Show field X

I hope someone can help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Azure DevOps, we can only [Create and manage inherited processes to customize the fields/rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav&viewFallbackFrom=azdevops).

To hide fields/groups, for some of the existing fields/groups (default fields/groups) we can directly hide them from the layout. For customized fields we can only remove them from the layout.

What you need, there is no such build-in option to achieve.

You could submit a user voice here: [Azure DevOps Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea)